# Python image reshape (1,28,28,1) is not work in image processing

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning

I have been stuck with this problem for a very long time and I could not find the solution.

**Problem:** I have to do "reshape" to practice the artificial intelligence I trained, but I couldn't do it. 
Normally it works when you take the same picture from the outside.

```py
def load_image(filename):
    img = load_img(filename, grayscale=True, target_size=(28, 28))
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = img.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
    img = img.astype('float32')
    img = img / 255.0
    return img
 
def run_example():
    img = load_image('images/5.png')
    model = load_model('final_model.h5')
    digit = model.predict_classes(img)
    print(digit[0])
 
run_example()
```

This code works, but when I want to get the numbers from a picture with a lot of numbers, I have to get the numbers from the inside.
[image]
I was able to get one of the numbers here and one of them is like this:

```py
digits_with_zeros[0].shape

# output: (171, 171)
```

When I try to apply "reshape" to this series, I get an error like this.

```py
img = digits_with_zeros[0].reshape(28,28)
img = img_to_array(img)
img = img.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
img = img.astype('float32')
img = img / 255.0

model = load_model('final_model.h5')
digit = model.predict_classes(img)
```

**output:**

```
----> 1 img = digits_with_zeros[0].reshape(-1,28,28,1)
      2 img = img_to_array(img)
      3 img = img.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
      4 img = img.astype('float32')
      5 img = img / 255.0

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 29241 into shape (28,28,1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img = digits_with_zeros[0]
img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(28, 28))
img = np.array(img).reshape(-1, 28,28,1)

model = load_model('final_model.h5')
digit = model.predict_classes(img)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.